# How to support undercurl in alacritty for windows?

Tags: terminal, alacritty

I installed alacritty version 0.13.0-dev (2df8f860) for windows and I am trying to get undercurl to be supported in the terminal. If I enter wsl, and then try `echo -e "\e[4:3mTEST"`, the expected output should be for TEST to have a curly underline, but is instead outputted as just normal text. How can alacritty be changed to support undercurl?

Comment: I have this issue too. It's nice to know that I am not the only one. I check in every couple of months and get the latest version to see if it's working yet. Are you sure this is a Windows thing? I have not tried Alacritty on Linux or Mac so I don't know.